# JavaScript : Selected File Names to JSON Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, file

My background is Android Developer but Trying to Create one useful snippet in HTML + PHP as its my passion.

I found following snippet to **choose files and display names** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21444800/1318946)

```js
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var list = document.getElementById('filelist');
  list.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    list.innerHTML += (i + 1) + '. ' + this.files[i].name + '\n';
  }
  if (list.innerHTML == '') list.style.display = 'none';
  else list.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple />
<pre id="filelist" style="display:none;"></pre>
```

## **What I want to do:**

I want to choose specific folder or multiple files (which contains ONLY `webp` files) and want to display JSON array of that selected files as below:

```
[
    {
        "image_file":"1.webp",
        "emojis":[
            "☕",
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "image_file":"2.webp",
        "emojis":[
            "",
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "image_file":"3.webp",
        "emojis":[
            "☕",
            ""
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please comment why are you down-voting? Is there any problem?

Comment: It is very much unclear what you actually want know. You have shown JavaScript code that selects files on the client side first, then you show PHP code that does that on the server side. No idea what the connection is supposed to be between those two different worlds. Start by clearly and unambiguously describing _where_ you want to select files from - the client file system, or the server file system?

Comment: Check Edited Question, Hope it will fully clear.

Comment: So collect the files in an appropriate data structure then, instead of writing them out as list items, and encode that data structure as JSON in the end.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: Finally I have created my own code : http://pratikbutani.com/wastickerapp/

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as below:

I just searched everything step by step and got it one by one.

```js
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  jsonObj = [];
  //var list = document.getElementById('filelist');
  //list.innerHTML = '';
  if (this.files.length>30){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 30 files");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      //list.innerHTML += (i + 1) + '. ' + this.files[i].name + '\n';
      item = {}
      item ["image_file"] = this.files[i].name;
      item ["emoji"] = [];

      item ["emoji"].push("");
      item ["emoji"].push("");

      jsonObj.push(item);

    }
  
   //document.getElementById('json').append(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2));
  
  output(syntaxHighlight(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, undefined, 2)));
 
   //if (list.innerHTML == '') list.style.display = 'none';
   //else list.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

function syntaxHighlight(json) {
    json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var cls = 'number';
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
    });
}

function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}
```

```css
pre { outline: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
.string { color: green; }
.number { color: darkorange; }
.boolean { color: blue; }
.null { color: magenta; }
.key { color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple accept=".webp" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="json"></div>
```

Thank you.